# Is there any way to use C++ MFC code in C# windows forms?

Tags: winforms, mfc

I am using one windows MFC C++ application but I want to change only UI part in C# windows forms.
Because in Windows Form UI is better than MFC. So, I want to change..

I there is any way to connect C++ as a application and C# as a DLL?...

Comment: While you *can* use [a Windows Form User Control in MFC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/using-a-windows-form-user-control-in-mfc) it's usually easier to write a C# Windows Forms application, and reference the code logic written in C++. The latter can be done using P/Invoke, [COM Interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/cominterop) or a mixed-mode assembly written in [C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp).